# Determine region of integration for homework problem

Tags: integration

For my Calc III homework problem, I am unsure how to determine the region of integration.

The problem is fairly simple.

$$
\text{Find the volume of the solid bounded by the planes }x = 0\text{, }y = 0\text{, }z = 0\text{, and }x + y + z = 7\text{.}
$$

Thinking this through, volume is easy especially because it is a solid. We can start with the following:
$$
\int\int\int_{D} xyz\:dA
$$
Just each of the sides multiplied together, all that's left is determining the region. Here's where I'm getting stuck.

I know I need to solve the plane for each variable and solve them all out systematically until I only have numbers for my outmost region, but I'm getting something wrong and I'm not sure if it's just a lapse in my algebraic knowledge or a lapse in understanding about the region itself.

First solving for x, for our innermost integral:
$$
x = 7 - y - z
$$
Then solving for y, for our second innermost integral:
$$
y = 7 - z - x\\
\text{Let's our previously solved x in to eliminate a variable}\\
y = 7 - z - (7 - y - z)\\
y = 7 - 7 - z + z + y\\
y = y \text{ (Clearly, I have failed to grasp something important.)}
$$

I can't use y = y for my bounds because this doesn't actually tell me what $a$ and $b$ are. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our height is in $z = 7-x-y$, thus in a similar manner what KfSsOc suggested we may write the volume $V$ as:

$\begin{align} 
V =\int_0^7 \int_0^{7-x} (7-x-y) \hspace{.1cm} dy \hspace{.05cm} dx 
\end{align} $

Essentially thinking we take our function of $z$, integrate it from the origin to its bound in $y$ (the line $y=7-x$), then we integrate the resulting function in $x$ from its numerical endpoints, and obtain our volume. A picture might help making the limits for integration more clear if you're having trouble.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain this. It was invaluable and also gave me the right answer (which is also helpful)

Answer (score 0):

**hint**:$$ V = \displaystyle \int_{0}^7 \int_{0}^{7-z} \int_{0}^{7-y-z} 1dxdydz$$